# What is the correct method for passing strings to labels?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a winform and I want to pass a series of strings to a series of labels.

This is the code:

```
   public partial class CourierDeliveringEnemyReport : Form
{
    public static string Label1 { get; set; }
    public static string Label2 { get; set; }
    public static string Label3 { get; set; }
    public static string Label4 { get; set; }
    public static string Label5 { get; set; }
    public string Label6 { get; set; }

    public CourierDeliveringEnemyReport()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = Label1;
        label2.Text = Label2;
        label3.Text = Label3;
        label4.Text = Label4;
        label5.Text = Label5;
        label6.Text = "This is a test!";
    }
```

The values get set here:

```
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport dlg = new CourierDeliveringEnemyReport();
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label1 = "Report from " + BlueArmy[GameEventList[i].ObservingUnit].Name; ;
                                string temp2 = "Enemy unit (" + RedArmy[GameEventList[i].Unit].Name + ") observed!";
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label2 = temp2;
                                string temp3 = "This intelligence is " + RedArmy[GameEventList[i].Unit].LastTimeObservedByEnemy + " minutes old.";
                                CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label3 = temp3;
```

Using the debugger I can confirm that valid strings are being passed. Label1, for example, contains the string "Report from...".

The problem is that the labels do not take the string values except for label6 (the test case).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the values for Label1 to Label5 properties? They need to be initialised before you use them - you are not binding the property to the label at that point.

Comment: It definitely compiles

Comment: Why are you trying to save label1 value into label1 again?
Try `label1.Text = Label1.Tostring`

Comment: @AzharAli, Label1 is a string. there is no string.Text, AFAIK

Comment: @user2864740 Label 1-5 are strings,  label1-6 are labels. The labels are in created in his designer.  Notice capitalization.  Not the same.  I don't see where he sets the string values however.

Comment: @Roman see above.  Label1 is a string, label1 is a label

Comment: label1.Text = Label1.ToString(); throws a runtime error

Comment: @JSON that is what I said :)... I think..

Comment: @Roman Not quite, Label1 is a string, label1 is a Label. He is not doing  he is doing label1.Text, not Label1.Text, thus Label.Text not string.Text.  NOtice capitalization. His variable names are confusing because he is a noob.  His problem is he thinks the labels will update when the strings are updated.  Not the case.

Comment: @zetar Not sure why you want to use static variables, when you could just set the Label.Text directly, but whatever.

Comment: How can I set the label text directly? When I try this: CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label1 = "Report from " + BlueArmy[GameEventList[i].ObservingUnit].Name;  it doesn't update the label.

Comment: @zetar, you are setting the string, not the label.  The label is not going to update when the string is updated, only the string will be updated.  You have to set the Text property everytime

Comment: label1.Text =  "Report from " + BlueArmy[GameEventList[i].ObservingUnit].Name;

Comment: I understand that label1.Text would be the normal way to set it. HOWEVER, I am in another namespace and I can't do it this way. That's why I was using public static string Label1 { get; set; } to try and set a string and then update it. But, it's not working

Comment: @zetar I know you have accepted an answer, but you should know when the properties are members of the form and you want to use them only for updating those labels, using data-binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is pointless and too much work. It's enough to create some public properties in the form which assign values to labels.

Comment: @zetar  Your problem is you assume that strings are copied by reference. However, this is not the case.  Strings are copied by value and NOT by reference.  Thus, changing the value of one, WILL NOT effect the other.  They are two separate variables pointing to two separate memory locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not `binding` the label to the variable, you are only setting it once. It seems you're expecting the label to update anytime the relative `LabelX` string is updated but this would only happen if there was a notification of some sort.

Your form, for example, can implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) and your `Label` properties can raise the notification when they're changed.

```
public partial class CourierDeliveringEnemyReport : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then it can be implemented in a manner similar to this

```
private string _label1;

public string Label1
{
    get { return _label1; }
    set
    {
        if(_label1 == value) return;

        _label1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Label1");
    }
}

//implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

Since this is WinForms, there's no XAML markup to add bindings so you can do it in the code behind with [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public CourierDeliveringEnemyReport()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    //"Text" is the property on the control to get/set (i.e. Label1.Text)
    //this is the datasource
    //"Label1" is the property in our code
    label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "Label1"))

    //add bindings for other labels
}
```

(Code is untested but should give an idea)

Comment: This seems like a way over complicated solution.

Comment: It's not complicated, just verbose. There are other ways of setting up notifications but `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a standard interface to implement for this pattern.

Comment: In theory, if the variables will remain in the code behind of the form, the `setter` could just directly access the control and set the text. Would tightly couple the code though if that's an issue.

Comment: I guess I don't get why you need to do all that.  Just set the Text property of the Label seems easy enough

Comment: I agree, that would definitely be the way to go, I'm just assuming there's a reason why it can't be done (might be wrong haha)

Comment: Verbose and overcomplicated mean pretty much the same thing.  This solution is like using a shotgun to kill a fly.  Completely unnecessary.  Do you think this guy is going to understand anything you have put on here?  He doesn't even understand why his Labels aren't getting updated.

Comment: He will not be the only person reading this post in the future and he's welcome to accept another answer. Relax, I even agreed with you that the simple route is the way to go. Seems you're going out your way to complain at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply create public properties which get and set those labels text?

When the properties are members of the form and you want to use them only for updating those labels, using data-binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is pointless and too much work. It's enough to create some public properties in the form which assign values to labels:

```
public string Value1
{
    get { return this.label1.Text; }
    set { this.label1.Text = value; }
}

int value2;
public int Value2
{
    get { return value2; }
    set 
    {
        value2 = value;
        this.label2.Text = string.Format("Here is the value {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to set those properties to see is as text of those labels.

```
var f = new ReportForm() {Value1 = "text for label1", Value2 = 100};
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are initialising the Labelx properties BEFORE they have been assigned in the constructor. At that point they will return null, so the label has no content.

You may need another method to update the labels AFTER any update to the Labelx property.

```
public partial class CourierDeliveringEnemyReport : Form
{
public static string Label1 { get; set; }
public static string Label2 { get; set; }
public static string Label3 { get; set; }
public static string Label4 { get; set; }
public static string Label5 { get; set; }
public string Label6 { get; set; }

public CourierDeliveringEnemyReport()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UpdateLabels();  // this will clear all labels except Label6
}
public void UpdateLabels()
{
    label1.Text = Label1;
    label2.Text = Label2;
    label3.Text = Label3;
    label4.Text = Label4;
    label5.Text = Label5;
    label6.Text = "This is a test!";
}


CourierDeliveringEnemyReport dlg = new CourierDeliveringEnemyReport();
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label1 = "Report from " + BlueArmy[GameEventList[i].ObservingUnit].Name; ;
string temp2 = "Enemy unit (" + RedArmy[GameEventList[i].Unit].Name + ") observed!";
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label2 = temp2;
string temp3 = "This intelligence is " + RedArmy[GameEventList[i].Unit].LastTimeObservedByEnemy + " minutes old.";
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label3 = temp3;
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.UpdateLabels();
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about binding in WinForms, so if keyboardP's solution works - then I would suggest that as the best way to go.

Comment: I'm sure it will work using data-binding. But when the properties are member of the form and you want to use them only for updating those labels, using data-binding and `INotifyPropetyChanged` is pointless and too much work. It's enough to create some public properties in the form which assign values to labels.  Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464913/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

You are running a constructor:

```
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport dlg = new CourierDeliveringEnemyReport();
```

Which assigns label controls *unassigned* Label# properties. 
Either do as PaulF suggested, by updating label controls afterwards, or pass string values for your Label# properties into constructor,  assign them, and then do your :`label1.Text = Label1;`

Pseudo example:

```
public CourierDeliveringEnemyReport(string l1, string l2, string l3, string l4, string l5, string l6)
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Label1 = l1;
    Label2 = l2;
    /* and so on */
    label1.Text = Label1;
    label2.Text = Label2;
    label3.Text = Label3;
    label4.Text = Label4;
    label5.Text = Label5;
    label6.Text = "This is a test!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
  public partial class CourierDeliveringEnemyReport : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static string Label1 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Label1;
        } 
        set
        {
            Label1=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Label1");
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    public CourierDeliveringEnemyReport()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = Label1;
        label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "Label1"));       
    }
}
```

Now when you change the value of Label1 it will be automatically updated to the actual label binds to it.

```
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport dlg = new CourierDeliveringEnemyReport();
CourierDeliveringEnemyReport.Label1 = "Report from " + BlueArmy[GameEventList[i].ObservingUnit].Name; ;
```